# How to make the textinput and textarea align side by side?

Tags: html, css

I have a contact form that contains 4 text input/s and 1 text area.

The contact form code is like this:

```
 <form class="contact_form"> 
    <input type="text" placeholder="Name"> 
    <input type="text" placeholder="Company">  
    <input type="email" placeholder="Email"> 
    <input type="text" placeholder="Contact No."> 
    <textarea placeholder="Your Enquiry"></textarea>
 </form>
```

Current CSS is this:

```
 .contact_form input {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    width: 44%;
 }

 textarea {
    float: right;
 }
```

**Problem:** When I put a float right to text area. It leaves a space above it and looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/82urB.png

Output: The output that i want must look like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/98XNc.png

Comment: Also, apply the float to the input container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This Way:

```
<form class="contact_form"> 
    <div class="input-wrapper">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Name"> 
    <input type="text" placeholder="Company">  
    <input type="email" placeholder="Email"> 
    <input type="text" placeholder="Contact No."> 
    </div>
    <textarea placeholder="Your Enquiry"></textarea>
 </form>

 <style>
     .contact_form .input-wrapper {
         float: left;
         width: 44%;
         margin-right: 10px;
     }
     .contact_form input {
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
        width: 100%;
     }

     textarea {
        float: left;
     }
 </style>
```

Comment: Hi Bindiya, Thanks for your Reply. Your answer Works.. Just a follow up question.. Do you think it's alright to put a div inside <form> ?

Comment: yes,it is totally fine,form will submit only its input type controls.

Comment: its totally fine using div on anything

Comment: additional to the answer tho, make sure the outer div that contains all of those should have cleafix on it, else it will make every elements follows it messed up

Comment: @C-link anything that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<form class="contact_form"> 
        <textarea placeholder="Your Enquiry"></textarea>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Name"/>         
        <input type="text" placeholder="Company"/>  
        <input type="email" placeholder="Email/"> 
        <input type="text" placeholder="Contact No." />         
</form>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/hamix/bqbvrq8n/)

Answer (score 0):

add css to

```
textarea {
    float: right;
    margin-right:1100px;
    margin-top:-170px;
 }
```

It will give you result as shown in your output image.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a div around **input field**

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/worx6j9u/)**

```
.contact_form div {
    float:left;
    width: 44%;
}
.contact_form input {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    width: 100%;
}
textarea {
    margin-left:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried put the textarea first?

```
<form class="contact_form">
  <textarea placeholder="Your Enquiry"></textarea> 
  <input type="text" placeholder="Name"> 
  <input type="text" placeholder="Company">  
  <input type="email" placeholder="Email"> 
  <input type="text" placeholder="Contact No."> 
</form>
```